# Find triangle rectangle opposite side length

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, angle

In the right-angled triangle below, is it possible to find length $BC$ with only length $AC$ and angle $A$?

[image: triangle rectangle]

Comment: $BC=(AC)f(A)$, where $f$ is one of the basic trig functions.  I'll leave you to work out which one.

Comment: "Triangle rectangle" was a new phrase to me. It makes perfect sense (at least once I see the picture), but it's more common in English to use the less latin-ified "right-angled triangle".

Comment: Thanks, I translated literally I didn't know the english term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know Angle A and side length AC therefore to find side length BC you can use trigonometry.

$\tan\theta = \frac O A$ 
$\tan A = \frac{BC}{AC}$ 
$BC=\tan A\times AC$